# Trouble Displaying Selected Multiple Files with OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I'm having trouble displaying multiple file names with OpenFileDialog class.
I have already selected Multiselect set to true, and can select more than one file in the DialogBox, but only 1 file is printed in the TextBox1 area.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    ' Dialog Result
    Dim FilesSelected As DialogResult
    ' Are Files Selected?
    If (FilesSelected = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        ' If Files Identify Array
        Dim file() As String
        file = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        For Each file In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            TextBox1.Text = (CurDir() & "")
        Next
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be sure to have the **MultiLine** property for the TextBox set to true and resize it to have an acceptable height. Also set the **ScrollBars** property to Vertical

Then your code could be written in this way (without an explicit loop)

```
Dim txt = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, OpenFileDialog1.FileNames)
TextBox1.Text = txt
```

Comment: the text is not showing in the textbox. Should I take out the if dialog result statement?

Comment: This worked completely by me taking out the conditional if then statements. I don't know why or how I started down that road, but thank you. :)  I was literally about to spend another 2 hours reading the msdn Visual Reference file on arrays

Comment: Not for nothing but understanding arrays wouldn't be the worst thing in the world ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting Text each time in your foreach loop.

Comment: I've changed my current code to:  
    
    Dim file() As String  
    file = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames  
    TextBox1.Text = file  
    End If  

    End Sub  
    End Class  
  
Yet I still get the following error:  
Value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array of System.Array.

Comment: I'm not a VB guy but I would do a join like in Steve's answer.  You need to somehow aggregate the individual file names into a single string.